# How to Include include path (full or relative) in LS command results

Tags: rhel, ls

This command supplies almost all of the information which I need in the proper CSV format (filename,dateModified,size)

But I would also like to include the file's directory as a separate item within each line's output.
Is there a way to do that using ls or another rhel available command?

```
ls * -R --fu | awk '{ print $9","$6","$5}'
```

Answer (score 1):

I found an answer but I would hope that there's a simpler solution!    I was fortunate enough that all of the filenames in this directory and subdirectories begin with the same characters.    Here goes:

```
    find . -type f -exec ls --fu {} \; | awk '{ print $9","$6","$5}' | sed "s/ArchiveFile/,ArchiveFile/"
```

In essence, I use "find" to locate the file, ls to obtain the information and then a combination of awk, print and sed to produce the output.   sed inserts the needed comma before the letters "ArchiveFile"

Example Output:

```
    ./ISIS_2011FALL/CAT_01College/,ArchiveFile_MUR115.2011FALL.51917.zip,2016-12-11,29484
```